# Best way to extend unique so that it can work on a cell array of scalars

Tags: matlab

The Matlab function `unique` doesn't work on a cell array of scalars, e.g.

```
>> unique([1 2 3 1])

ans =

     1     2     3

>> unique({1 2 3 1})
Error using cell/unique (line 85)
Input A must be a cell array of strings.
```

What can I do to modify the unique function so that it can work on a cell array of scalars? i.e. I would like

```
>> unique({1 2 3 1})

ans =

     [1]     [2]     [3]
```

Comment: Does it have to stay as cells? `unique(cell2mat({1 2 3}))`

Comment: You mean you want to override the built-in `unique` with this additional functionality, but still have it be backwards compatible?

Comment: it doesn't have to stay as cells, but it would be really good if calling unique from some other function in matlab doesn't break the other function.

Comment: yes @kmac this is what I mean. Sorry, I had to delete me previous comment as `sortrows` doesn't actually use unique. But I have functions that use unique that break if it is applied to a cell array of scalars.

Comment: I haven't tried overriding built-in functions (it [seems](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103129-how-do-i-overload-built-in-matlab-functions) to be [possible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/1170)), but your custom function can just check if it's a cell (since only you will pass it that). `if iscell(x); unique(cell2mat(x)); else unique(x); end`.

Comment: P.S. You might be able to get away with not even testing the type, since the built-in functions are type specific. If you just put your `unique.m` with `unique(cell2mat(x))` in a folder called `@cell` (which apparently filters the input type), it might not affect the built-in.

Comment: that seems like a plausible answer, thanks

Comment: just curious, if it's composed of only of scalar why use a cell array in the first place?

Comment: The integers represent categories. Since these categories can sometimes be strings, it is better for my purpose to read everything into a cell array. So to be most accurate, I probably should not have any scalars, but instead convert them into strings or something.

Comment: Mmm, my solution won't be very helpful then ;). It assume only scalars. You're right to convert them all to strings if you have any strings, and then use the built-in unique...

Comment: I would not recommend write code where the type is not specified unless you have a function which will work as some tool. In this case it does still not seem reasonable to overwrite the `unique` function. This tool function would normally be short and an `if` would not be messy. In that case any collegue reading your code will assume it to work the same as unique

Answer (score 5):

I recommend to use either strings in a cell or doubles in a vector. Many functions like `unique` only apply to cell arrays of strings, not to any other cells.

```
unique({'1' '2' '3' '1'})
```

To convert the cell, use

```
cellfun(@num2str,{1,2,3,1},'uni',false)
```

Comment: memo: Don't code before the first coffee. Quotation marks fixed.